# Metal Render Loop optimization

Tags: avplayer, drawrect, metal, cvpixelbuffer, metalkit

I'm looking for some direction on how to *properly* implement a Metal render loop.  My render loop is being fed a stream of video frames from an `AVPlayer`.

Here's my current implementation:

1. A `CVDisplayLink` queries the `AVPlayerItemVideoOutput` of the player at 60hz.  If a new frame is there, it's `CVPixelBufferRef` is captured/saved* as a property of the `MTKView` to which it will be rendered.  (At this point, the previously captured video frame is released).
2. My `MTKView` is set up with `isPaused` and `enableSetNeedsDisplay` to `NO`. In other words, the internal timer of the `MTKView` is tasked with periodically calling its `drawRect` method.
3. In `drawRect` I first convert the newly-arrived* `CVPixelBuffer` to a `MTLTexture`, and then a bunch of rendering stages occur.
4. Finally, I call `presentDrawable` at the end of the `drawRect` method.

*Note: The mutex access to the `CVPixelBufferRef` is controlled by a pairing of  `dispatch_semaphore_wait` and `dispatch_semaphore_signal`.

**Is this a correct means of doing things?**  It seems fairly performant, though some frames are occasionally dropped.  In terms of timing, an Xcode profiling of Metal tells me my `MTLCommandBuffer` is typically taking under 3ms to run.

Having said that, I see some alternate possibilities:

- ditch the `CVDisplayLink` implementation and grab the frames inside of `drawRect`
- reverse the rendering process; display the *previously* captured frame & rendered `MTLTexture` first in the `drawRect` method and then `commit` that Metal command buffer and call `presentDrawable` promptly.  After that point, capture the next video frame and run it through its rendering stages *before* the next `drawRect` call (do so before `drawRect` exits?).

**Another issue:** I was under the impression that both the `CVDisplayLink` and `drawRect` methods were ***not*** running on the main thread with this configuration.  I'm troubled by the fact that whenever I let up on one of the app's menus, there's a significant stutter in the delivery of video frames -- this is symptomatic of the main thread doing UI updates and is blocking.  The same behaviour is observed when an on-screen `NSCollectionView` is reloaded and its contents are animated on the screen. This leads me to believe my assumption is incorrect. **How can these `MTKView` render loops be made to avoid these issues?**  Wondering if the entire opening/config of the `AVPlayer` needs to be off the main thread as well.

### UPDATE #1

I fixed the "**Another issue**" stuttering issues which would occur when mousing up on any `NSMenu` items.  This was my solution:

1. Configure each `MTKView` with `isPaused=YES` and `enableSetNeedsDisplay=NO`.  This means that explicit `draw` calls are needed for a view to render its content.
2. From within the `CVDisplayLink` callback, issue the `draw` call to the `MTKView` on a `dispatch_global_queue`, thusly:

---

```
__block MTKView *aView = ....;
dispatch_queue_t aQueue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
dispatch_async(aQueue, ^{ [aView draw]; });
```